# Does CNAME work at all for AppHarbor?

Tags: dns, appharbor

I've created a new application and would like to use a custom URL. Recently AppHarbor started charging for custom hostnames and I would rather not have to pay until I'm ready to go live.

Does anyone know if a CNAME will work? I've tried setting one up and I get a 404 error.

Comment: for a CNAME to work the host serving the pages must be expecting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned on this [AppHarbor support request](http://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/2944-does-cname-work-at-all), AppHarbor must know about the custom hostname to correctly route application requests based on the host header.

Once a hostname is configured on AppHarbor, CNAME DNS configuration will work just fine.